# Add Button at the top of a view iOS programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to program my app's view controller. It has buttons and textfields. I want to put my objects into another view (the one with color green background). The first Textfield should be at the very top of the green view.

I know how to make it center. But I need to put it starting at (0,0) of the green view.

Here's what I've done so far:

```
// add UI View For TextFields and Login Button
UIView *utc = [[UIView alloc] init];
utc.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
utc.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth * 0.95, 170);
utc.center = CGPointMake(screenWidth * 0.50, screenHeight * 0.68);
[self.view addSubview:utc];

// add textfield1
UITextField *emailTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, utc.frame.size.width, miniButtonWidth.height)];
emailTextField.center = CGPointMake(utc.frame.size.width * 0.5, utc.frame.size.height * 0.01);
emailTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
emailTextField.background = [UIImage imageNamed:@"textfieldLogIn.png"];
emailTextField.placeholder = @"Email Address";
emailTextField.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[utc addSubview:emailTextField];
```

I'm using the same way (configuring the frame and center) of the views in my other Viewcontroller, and the design looks perfectly nice, just in this case, I can't put the textfield at the very top. I'm new in iOS.

[image]

Comment: You want the text field at the top of the green UIView?

Comment: I want the textfield to be at the beginning of the green UIView sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `emailTextField` at the top left, but still centered, than just initialize it with those values and don't edit the center.

```
UITextField *emailTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, utc.frame.size.width, miniButtonWidth.height)];
```

`emailTextField` will be at the top left and you won't have to center it because it is already the width of the `utc`.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. I think I have wasted my 1 hour figuring this out.  So much time wasted. One guy posted his answer before you did, but someone down voted his answer and it was deleted a while ago, but it works. He said I just need to comment out the code for center.

Comment: I would refrain from using the `center` property. It's one extra line. The first 2 parameters of `CGRectMake()` are the x and y origin. To center just take `(outside view - inside view)/2`.

Comment: In your case the x origin would be `0` because both outside(superview) and inside have the same width.